# symfony2: add parameters.yml.dist in config.yml

Tags: symfony

Im trying to add `parameters.yml.dist` inside `config.yml` this way:

```
- { resource: parameters.yml }
- { resource: parameters.yml.dist }

twig:
    debug:            %kernel.debug%
    strict_variables: %kernel.debug%
    globals:
      base_url_algoritmo: %base_url_algoritmo%  <<<<<<< this parameter is inside paramters.yml.dist
```

but I get

> [Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException]
>   Cannot load resource "parameters.yml.dist".

Comment: dont' use the dist file. Read This http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-3-interactive-management-of-the-parameters-yml-file

Comment: Doing a composer install will move the missing keys from .dist to .yml.

Comment: Just don't do that. You are missing the point of having a parameters.yml.dist AND a parameters.yml.

Answer (score 3):

".dist" is used only for distribution (dummy data that will be used on composer install/update) - so this idea of including it in config.yml is not so good ;)